# spring-data-flow problem to undeploy streams deployed on a docker platform with Kafka and Oracle

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

We are looking for SCDF to deploy our applications.
Actually, I use skipper-server 2.3 dataflow-server 2.4 and kafka deployed as dockers.
When I am on a local server, we don't have any problems but when we are deployed on a docker platform, the deployment and the destroy of streams are OK. But we can't un-deploy them by the GUI and the dataflow-server-shell.
In the log, we have this trace :

```
skipper            | 2020-02-19 14:30:58.451  INFO 1 --- [eTaskExecutor-2] o.s.c.s.s.s.DeleteDeleteAction           : About to delete testStreamSftpDataflowlaunch1
skipper            | 2020-02-19 14:30:58.471  INFO 1 --- [eTaskExecutor-2] o.s.c.d.spi.local.LocalAppDeployer       : Un-deploying app with deploymentId testStreamSftpDataflowlaunch1.sftp-dataflow-v1 instance 0.
skipper            | 2020-02-19 14:31:28.525  INFO 1 --- [eTaskExecutor-2] o.s.s.support.LifecycleObjectSupport     : stopped org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor@5a876edb
skipper            | 2020-02-19 14:31:28.525  INFO 1 --- [eTaskExecutor-2] o.s.s.support.LifecycleObjectSupport     : stopped DELETE_DELETE DELETE_EXIT  /  / uuid=cfb0fc42-6277-430a-9c39-05e3f14be373 / id=testStreamSftpDataflowlaunch1
skipper            | 2020-02-19 14:31:28.525  INFO 1 --- [eTaskExecutor-2] o.s.c.s.s.s.StateMachineConfiguration    : Entering state ObjectState [getIds()=[INITIAL], getClass()=class org.springframework.statemachine.state.ObjectState, hashCode()=1492058631, toString()=AbstractState [id=INITIAL, pseudoState=org.springframework.statemachine.state.DefaultPseudoState@6409e9d2, deferred=[], entryActions=[], exitActions=[org.springframework.cloud.skipper.server.statemachine.ResetVariablesAction@7139bd31], stateActions=[], regions=[], submachine=null]]
skipper            | 2020-02-19 14:31:28.525  INFO 1 --- [eTaskExecutor-2] o.s.c.s.s.s.SkipperStateMachineService   : setting future value org.springframework.cloud.skipper.domain.Release@7bab1e28

skipper |
---------

 2020-02-19 14:31:28.525  INFO 1 --- [eTaskExecutor-2] o.s.s.support.LifecycleObjectSupport     : started org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor@5a876edb
skipper            | 2020-02-19 14:31:28.525  INFO 1 --- [eTaskExecutor-2] o.s.s.support.LifecycleObjectSupport     : started DELETE_DELETE DELETE_EXIT  /  / uuid=cfb0fc42-6277-430a-9c39-05e3f14be373 / id=testStreamSftpDataflowlaunch1
```

However, the stream is already available.

Answer (score 0):

The DELETE_EXIT from Skipper state machine confirms that the deletion of the release (undeployment of the stream) exits successfully.

Looks like there are some issues when it comes to undeploying the apps that are part of the stream. Could you share more debug logs (especially the deployer side of things) to understand what went wrong when the associated apps were undeployed by Skipper server?

Comment: I add this parameter to the skipper ser and dataflow ser launcher - logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.local=DEBUG\  but the log is too large. How can I send the log? the last line is ] o.s.s.support.LifecycleObjectSupport     : started  org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor@2bd88d71
[34mskipper            |[0m 2020-02-20 16:36:19.154  INFO 1 --- [eTaskExecutor-4] o.s.s.support.LifecycleObjectSupport     : started DELETE_DELETE DELETE_EXIT  /  / uuid=6008d397-042e-4581-ae99-7e3974a6ab00 / id=testStreamSftpDataflowlaunch12
Regards